# Function wp_post_update breake the foreach loop, no errors, no id response. Why?

Tags: php, wordpress

In my wordpress plugin i have follow code:

```
$args = array(
    'post_status'    => 'draft',
    'category'       => 1,
    'post_type'      => array('page', 'post', 'attachment' ),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);
$allposts = get_posts($args);

foreach ( $allposts as $key => $post ) {

    $update = [];
    $update['ID'] = $post->ID;
    $update['post_title'] = 'post title';
    $update['post_name'] = 'post-name';


    $post_id = wp_update_post( $update , true);
    //fail, loop stopped without any errors 
    var_dump($post_id); //never happens

}
```

`$allposts` contains valid array of post objects

The first iteration update first post, but `wp_update_post` returns absolutely nothing, no errors, no post id, nothing

so next iteration never starts...

that code has works perfect before, but at one of the moment has broken

what happened here?

p.s. on other blog this code still works perfect

Comment: Are you sure the "post_name" you are passing in is unique? What happens if your update array contains only the ID? Also, try setting `wp_error` to true and then checking for an error message: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post#Example

Comment: if conatains only ID, still same error

Comment: wp_error dont allowed, wp_update_post returns nothing, even false, true, id, errors

Comment: Does code is working now?

Comment: Yep, was memory problem

Comment: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes)

Answer (score 0):

check this below code working in my system with publish post status.

```
add_action ('init',array( $this, 'updateAllPost'));
public function updateAllPost()
{
 $args = array(
 'post_status'    => 'draft',
 'category'       => 1,
 'post_type'      => array('page', 'post', 'attachment' ),
 'posts_per_page' => -1,
 );
 $allposts = get_posts($args);

foreach ( $allposts as $key => $post ) {

    $update = array(
    "ID"=>$post->ID,
    "post_title"=>"post title",
    "post_name"=>"post-name"
    );
    $post_id = wp_update_post( $update , true);
    //fail, loop stopped without any errors 
  var_dump($post_id); //never happens
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but no see difference... my code broken only at one site, on other it works fine... confused

Comment: where you are writing this function and which action are you using? or when you are calling this function?

Comment: When i put your code out of my plugin class, they work

Comment: But inside public function of my plugin class, they not work

Comment: can i see your plugin file have you declared a class?

Comment: admin_post_ucbtr_rename_titles  catch post with data from form and process titles rename

Comment: put add_action in your constructor and check it

Comment: @OswellESpencerUmbrella-Corp if you have more information to add, please update your question instead of adding it in comments. Firstly its easier to format code (you can't use line breaks in a comment) and also, anyone else who looks at your question will see it.